# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I am getting the following exception while trying to write an `.xlsx file using Apache POI`

```
NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException
```

Here's the Code Snippet:-

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(100);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:\\workspace\\April\\Excel Test\\workbook.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
```

I have the following jars included

- dom4j-1.6.1
- poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL
- poi-3.6-20091214
- xmlbeans-2.3.0
- ooxml-schemas-1.0

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here or i am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the stax API jar

If you look at the [POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) you'll see that the ooxml-schemas jar depends on a STAX API jar (most typically provided by `stax-api-1.0.1.jar`)

Look in your POI binary download, and in the `ooxml-lib` directory you'll see the jar you need. Alternately, if you use Maven, it'll download the dependency for you