# How to read .xlsx file in java 1.5?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried with  below .jar files .

1.xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

2.poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL .jar

3.poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar

4.dom4j-1.6.jar

But I am getting exception as below.

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException`

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildMethod(XmlBeans.java:174)

at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:195)

at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildNodeToCursorMethod(XmlBeans.java:232)

at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:131)

at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:44)
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259901/how-do-i-solve-the-xmlstreamexception

Comment: Upgrade your Java to a modern version, at least 7 (1.7)

Answer (score 2):

You should add two additional jars to the classpath of your application when using XmlBeans 2.3.0 or higher with JDK prior to 1.6:
**xmlbeans-qname.jar** and **xbean.jar**

From XmlBeans 2.6.0 release notes:

> Starting with XmlBeans 2.6.0, binary files are compatible with JDK1.6.
>   Sources are still compatible with JDK 1.4. When using JDK 1.4,
>   xmlbeans-qname.jar is required on classpath of your application
>   alongside xbean.jar.