# Apache POI - how to create workbook for xlsx

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When working with just `xls` I can create workbooks just fine, however when working with `xlsx` I cant seem to get it to work.

I am using the `poi-ooxml.jar` and am trying to use the command

```
new XSSFWorkbook();
```

However I get an error message everytime, any thoughts?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at Testing2.main(Testing2.java:20)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

Comment: Do u want the thoughts about what error are u getting? Better post the error message and then seek thoughts about why/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400096/write-a-file-in-xlsx-format-using-apache-poi Here you have required jars and small code. Please post error code too for appropriate answer.

Comment: sorry, there is the lengthy error message

Comment: So from the little Ive discovered so far, it looks as though I need more jars.  Should I also be including stax-api and xmlbeans ?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI Dependency and Component](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) .  You might be missing:

For poi-ooxml you need it's dependencies

1. poi,
2. poi-ooxml-schemas
3. dom4j
4. poi-ooxml-version-yyyymmdd.jar

Although Not related to your question try to search for stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

This will help you in long run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra 2 jars to make POI work on (.xlsx) Excel file.

1.first you need to import all the jar [poi-3.9](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

2.Add [xmlbeans2.3.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeans230jar.htm) and [dom4j-1.6.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddom4j16jar.htm) to your classpath. These 2 jars are the dependency jars for handling .xlsx Excel file in POI Library.

Maven project add below dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.9</version> 
</dependency>
```

so  programming for creating exls sheet

```
 package com.loknath.lab;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


public class ReadWriteXL
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{

System.out.println("Write data to an Excel Sheet");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("D:/temp/1.xlsx");
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("email");
HSSFRow row;
HSSFCell cell;
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) i);
cell = row.createCell(i);

cell.setCellValue("string value added");
}

workBook.write(fos);

}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to download the binary distribution from http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Add the jars into your libraries and it should resolve the error

Be sure to add all the jars not just the poi-ooxml